# Pass a parameter through a shortcut on a PowerShell script (.ps1)

Tags: powershell, parameters, shortcut

I'm trying to pass an argument through a shortcut on the script I need. So I've done my shortcut and in the "Target" field I've written my parameter "Test" (C:\Users\MBGR\Desktop\test2.ps1 Test).

In my script I have the "$args[0]" to recieve my parameter. When I'm sending a parameter through Execute from Win7 (powershell.exe -noexit C:\users\MBGR\Desktop\test2.ps1 TEST) it's working great. And also via CMD.

So my question is why is that not working with a shortcut? It's something that work well with VBS, is there a little something I'm missing to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the Powershell executable in front of the script in the Target editbox.

**Example**

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\users\MBGR\Desktop\test2.ps1 Test

Comment: As I can't answer at my own question before 5 hours... I'm posting here, That's it ! Thanks for that really quick and useful answer ^^. I didn't know that you had to specify the application even in the shortcut.

Have a nice day and thanks again.